# Trying to use pd.read_html to extract information and export data to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to extract the information from the table on this Wikipedia page to automate data collection.

Link to webpage: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_members_of_the_17th_Lok_Sabha

I am using pd.read_html to see the information as a dataframe. I want to be able to export the module to a .csv file so I can store and analyze the data.

When I got to change the data to a traditional dataframe, I am only able to extract information from the first table. I want to be able to extract the infromation from all the pages on the table.

I am able to create a dataframe for each table, but this is not super efficient nor does it seem best practice.

This is the code I've used to extract information, but it only returns one table.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

members = []

wikiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_members_of_the_17th_Lok_Sabha'
page = requests.get(wikiUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
for table in tables:
    members.append(table)

frame = pd.read_html(str(members))

df=pd.DataFrame(frame[0])
print(df)
```

I tried just using the "frame" variable so I could do all the tables.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

members = []

wikiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_members_of_the_17th_Lok_Sabha'
page = requests.get(wikiUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'wikitable sortable'})
for table in tables:
    members.append(table)

frame = pd.read_html(str(members))

df=pd.DataFrame(frame, dtype=object)
print(df)

df.to_csv('India 17th Lok Sabha.csv')
```

But it prints the following:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  values = np.array([convert(v) for v in values])
                                                    0
0        #     Constituency  ... Party            ...
1      #    Constituency          Name  Party     ...
2        #              Constituency  ... Party   ...
3        #       Constituency  ... Party          ...
4        #  Constituency              Name  Party ...
5      # Constituency                Name  Party  ...
6        #         Constituency  ... Party        ...
7       #          Constituency  ... Party        ...
8      # Constituency  ... Party                  ...
9        #    Constituency  ... Party             ...
10       #         Constituency  ... Party        ...
11       #        Constituency  ... Party         ...
12       #    Constituency  ... Party             ...
13       #            Constituency  ... Party     ...
14     #        Constituency  ... Party           ...
15     #   Constituency           Name  Party     ...
16     #  Constituency           Name  Party      ...
17     # Constituency  ... Party                  ...
18       #        Constituency  ... Party         ...
19       #          Constituency  ... Party       ...
20       #          Constituency  ... Party       ...
21     # Constituency              Name  Party    ...
22       #       Constituency  ... Party          ...
23       #       Constituency  ... Party          ...
24     #       Constituency             Name  Part...
25       #      Constituency  ... Party           ...
26     #               Constituency  ... Party    ...
27       #          Constituency  ... Party       ...
28     #                 Constituency  ... Party  ...
29     # Constituency         Name  Party         ...
30     #  ...                                 Part...
31     # Constituency  ... Party                  ...
32     # Constituency                     Name  Pa...
33     #      Constituency                  Name  ...
34     #           Constituency             Name  ...
35     # Constituency             Name  Party     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To load all tables from the wiki page to one dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_members_of_the_17th_Lok_Sabha"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

dfs = []
for table in soup.select("table.wikitable"):
    name = table.find_previous("h2").span.text
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    df["Region"] = name
    df = df.drop(columns=["#", "Party"])
    df = df.rename(columns={"Party.1": "Party"})
    dfs.append(df)

df_out = pd.concat(dfs)

# print first 20 items from the DataFrame:
print(df_out.head(20).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Constituency | Name | Party | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Araku (ST) | Goddeti Madhavi | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Srikakulam | Ram Mohan Naidu Kinjarapu | Telugu Desam Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Vizianagaram | Bellana Chandra Sekhar | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Visakhapatnam | M. V. V. Satyanarayana | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Anakapalli | Beesetti Venkata Satyavathi | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Kakinada | Vanga Geetha | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Amalapuram (SC) | Chinta Anuradha | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Rajahmundry | Margani Bharat | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Narasapuram | Raghu Rama Krishna Raju | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Eluru | Kotagiri Sridhar | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Machilipatnam | Vallabhaneni Balasouri | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Vijayawada | Kesineni Srinivas | Telugu Desam Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Guntur | Galla Jayadev | Telugu Desam Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Narasaraopet | Lavu Sri Krishna Devarayalu | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Bapatla (SC) | Nandigam Suresh | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Ongole | Magunta Sreenivasulu Reddy | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Nandyal | Pocha Brahmananda Reddy | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Kurnool | Sanjeev Kumar | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Anantapur | Talari Rangaiah | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |
| Hindupur | Kuruva Gorantla Madhav | YSR Congress Party | Andhra Pradesh |